# Linux startup- taskbar has disappeared and terminal won't fire up but can copy files

Tags: linux, ubuntu

My taskbars have disappeared on Ubuntu Mate 17.10, and I cannot launch a terminal or System Settings but can run Eclipse. Assuming I've accidentally deleted some folder, what might that be? I was playing with /usr/bin and /usr/lib today, but they seem to look somewhat sane- not empty.

I did get rid of Python2 and all it's dependencies at one point today, could that be a cause?

Presently following instructions listed here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/748289/how-to-repair-ubuntu-installation-after-broken-dist-upgrade-without-losing-any-c

EDIT:
Those instructions above fixed it.

Comment: Boot Ubuntu Live. You can compare the directories on the live system with your installation, but you might be save time in the long run to re-install over the top of your existing installation. Needless to say, back up first.

Comment: Thanks, I've already fixed it by dropping to termina with Ctrl+F1l, updating, upgrading, and reinstalling desktop as suggested for the other problem.

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept it, so that others can see that it has been solved.

Comment: Alt+F2 then type `r` and hit enter, and it will fix the taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually know what happened- it's possible I deleted important files, but it's also possible the installers messed up. At any rate, dropping down to terminal with Ctrl+F1, updating packages, upgrading the system, and reinstalling the desktop worked, as suggested here for someone with a different issue.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/748289/how-to-repair-ubuntu-installation-after-broken-dist-upgrade-without-losing-any-c